# Embedding Timestamp-Based Metadata in FLAC Files

Tags: metadata, timecode, flac, file, files

I’m working on a project where I’ve generated an audio file. Now, I need to associate specific timestamps with text data within that file. I’m currently using FLAC, but I’m open to other lossless options. The goal is to have this metadata display automatically in audio players during playback.

The data I want to embed will be about “`..this much text...`”, and I plan to evenly distribute that across the duration of the file at regular interval timestamps. This is to give users an idea of the stats at that particular point in the session.

I’m hoping to leverage something that already exists, so I don’t have to write my own audio player! I understand that FLAC files support robust metadata, but I’m not sure how to go about embedding this specific type of timestamp-based metadata, while having it be read and displayed automatically by most players. Maybe an embedded cue sheet? Maybe UFID:TXXX?

Comment: You might look into embedded lyrics - but that's going to be for mp3/aac. idk about flac, but I never use it myself because Macs hate flac [& ogg]. Nothing supports it.

Comment: I’m not what constitutes “most players” in terms of this question. I don’t think I have a player of any kind that displays text along with audio unless you count lyrics in the Spotify app. If I wanted something truly portable along these lines I’d just make a video file instead.

Comment: Sounds like embedded synced lyrics or the TITLE part of an embedded cuesheet will work then.

Comment: Look into the now discontinued empeg/rio car. We had a 3rd party plugin that would display the lyrics at the correct timestamp through the song. And while it was an mp3/wav player, it could also play flac (can't remember if that was a 3rd party mod or not) - browse https://empegbbs.com/